# Agrupar dados repetidos de um determinada coluna

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso fazer um select e agrupar os itens, mas como tenho pesquisado, minha consulta vai vir de um banco de dados selecionado por uma variavel via post, e vou listar as colunas que estao num while vindo via post de uma variavel tambem.

O problema é agrupar a coluna que está no while e seus resultados `!<br><br>`
(eu adiciono as colunas dinamicamente pra eu poder listar mais "facilmente" depois no select, gravando como campo1, campo2 e por ai vai)

[image: a imaggem pra ter uma ideia]

No caso da imagem estou selecionando por um campo especifico e não pela variável vindo via POST. A listagem produto, lado, etc... ta listado abaixo com as colunas com nome campo1, campo2,etc

ex.:

```
    <p>:: Cadatre a Ultima Compra do Cliente</p>
<?php
    $fila = 'grafica';//$_POST['bd'];
    $pega = $fila.'_lista';
$mostrando = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $pega order by cod asc " )or die (mysql_error());
    while ($vendo = mysql_fetch_array($mostrando)) {
$campo = $vendo['campo'];

        echo '<div class="_cliente">'.$campo.'</div>';
    }   

    ?>

    <select name="prods" class="input_prod" style="clear: left;">
<?php   
        $prod = mysql_query("SELECT campo1 FROM $fila group by campo1 order by cod asc ") or die(mysql_error());    
    while ($listar = mysql_fetch_array($prod)){

        $campo1 = $listar['campo1'];

        echo '<option value="'.$campo1.'" title="'.$campo1.'">'.$campo1.'</option>';
    }
        ?>

</select>
```

esse exemplo acima é como listei na imagem enviada, porem preciso fazer um SELECT dinamicamente.

Comment: Sabes usar jQuery?

Comment: aqui os nomes estão sem `.`  (ponto), portanto lá na outra pergunta editei para nomes de colunas sem ponto!

Comment: @MarceloUchimura uso praticamento o jquery em todas requisições!..

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo ajustei a resposta anterior na necessidade que tinha, agora ta mais complicadinho o esquema

Comment: cara, não sei se é viável no seu caso mas você poderia ter no lugar de consultas dinâmicas, consultas por um agrupador maior trazendo a massa de dados pra aplicação e fazendo o agrupamento na aplicação mesmo... dependendo do caso daria pra jogar o processamento pro cliente em javascript